# syntax error by using Join MS-sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, syntax

The data structure is

```
TABLE a
Dates            Ticker_Name  Price
02/01/2013    cc1                  ***
02/01/2013    cc2                  ***
02/01/2013    cc3
02/01/2013    tt1
02/01/2013    tt2
02/01/2013    tt3
02/02/2013    cc2
02/02/2013    cc3

TABLE b
Dates                  cc               tt
02/01/2013             cc2              tt1
02/02/2013             cc3              tt2
```

Suppose given date range and the column name in b, I want to first find the coresponding cc codes, cc2 on 02/01/2013 and cc3 on 02/02/2013. Then find the price in table a.

I wrote

```
select a.Dates, a.Ticker_Name, a.Price
From a
INNER JOIN b 
ON a.Dates = b.Dates
AND a.Ticker_Name = b.CL
WHERE b.Dates BETWEEN #03/01/2013# AND #05/01/2013#
```

But access 2010 said syntax error in JOIN operation. Any idea?

Comment: the data structure is ticker_name(text) price(number) cc(text) tt(text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table b does not have a column named CL.  You refer to it here:

```
INNER JOIN b 
ON a.Dates = b.Dates
AND a.Ticker_Name = b.CL  -- <<==
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.dates, 
       a.ticker_name, 
       a.price 
FROM   a 
       INNER JOIN b 
               ON a.dates = b.dates 
                  AND a.ticker_name = b.cc 
WHERE  b.dates BETWEEN #03/01/2013# AND #05/01/2013#
```

What exactly is b.cl? I don't see this in your structure? This is likely causing the issue. I have replaced it above with b.cc